# Regular expression for a (nested) html tags

Tags: python, regex

I have the following text: `<p class="class">lorem</p> <p >ipsum</p > <p><p>lorem ipsum</p></p>`
and I need to make of it four groups (with regural expressions):

1. `<p class="class">lorem</p>`
2. `<p >ipsum</p >`
3. `<p><p>lorem ipsum</p></p>`
4. `<p>lorem ipsum</p>`

I think I should do it in this way:

1. `<p></p>` - for paragraphs
2. `<p\s></p\s*>` - for a whitespace after `<p` and unlimited whitespaces before `>`
3. `<p\s.*></p\s*>` - for any char before `p>` (for classes etc.)
4. `<p\s.*>.*</p\s*>` - for any value of paragraph

But now, If I have `<p>Lorem</p> <p>Ipsum</p>` I get one group `['<p>Lorem</p> <p>Ipsum</p>']`. I understand why but I don't know to improve it because I need to have two groups `['<p>Lorem</p>', '<p>Ipsum</p>']`. How you any ideas?

PS: I use Python with re module.

Comment: Read this immortal answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Your mistake is thinking that regex is the right tool to parse HTML. It isn't; HTML easily gets too complex for a regex to be the right tool; HTML is not a nail, so put down the hammer! Use a HTML parser instead. Use BeautifulSoup, for example.

Comment: Note that `<p><p>lorem ipsum</p></p>` isn't even valid HTML; proper 'repairing' parsers will strip the outer `<p>` tag.

Comment: Yeah, I could use ready tools but I'd like to do it on my own, for training. But thanks for links. I'll read those answers and analyse BeautifulSoup code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In re `.*` is greedy meaning it will match as much text as possible. Add a `?` to make text not greedy as so:

```
 <p\s.*?>.*?</p\s*?>
```

Here is the documentation:

```
*?, +?, ??

The '*', '+', and '?' qualifiers are all greedy; they match as much text as possible. 
Sometimes this behaviour isn’t desired; if the RE <.*> is matched against 
'<H1>title</H1>', it will match the entire string, and not just '<H1>'. Adding '?' 
after the qualifier makes it perform the match in non-greedy or minimal fashion; as
few characters as possible will be matched. Using .*? in the previous expression will 
match only '<H1>'.
```

Documentation is available here:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: This is not correct for other tags. Ex:- `<div><div></div></div>` .  This pattern will return `<div><div></div>`.